# Strange behaviour of Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am working on a Laravel app and I am trying to convert some dates to a different timezone and format with the timezone in the string. Here is the code, I've got:

```
public static function convertDateToUserTimezone($date, $timezone = '', $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $userTimezone = auth()->user()->timezone;
    $timeFormat = $format . $timezone;

    return (Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date))->setTimezone($userTimezone)->format($timeFormat);
}
```

and I am calling this function in the following:

```
Class:convertDateToUserTimezone($date, 'ZZ');
```

for example for this datetime: `2022-08-09 22:39:36` I expect to get `2022-08-10 01:39:36+0300`

as the default Laravel timezone is UTC and I am converting to `Europe/Sofia` but I get this: `2022-08-10 01:39:361080010800`. Why is the timezone not in the format I requested?

I haven't used Carbon much so there is probably something I am missing.

Tried googling various things but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your format is wrong. 'ZZ' calls the `Z` format character twice and that's not the format character you want.

Here's an extract of the possible formats. You can view the full table at https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

| format character | Description | Example returned values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O | Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) without colon between hours and minutes | Example: +0200 |
| P | Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes | Example: +02:00 |
| p | The same as P, but returns Z instead of +00:00 (available as of PHP 8.0.0) | Example: +02:00 |
| T | Timezone abbreviation, if known; otherwise the GMT offset. | Examples: EST, MDT, +05 |
| Z | Timezone offset in seconds.The offset for timezones west of UTC is always negative, and for those east of UTC is always positive. | -43200 through 5040 |

`ZZ` is giving you `1080010800` (`10800` twice.) This is consistent with the timezone you set. `Europe/Sofia` is GMT+3. 10800 seconds = 180 minutes = 3 hours.

Based on your function and this table, I'd say you want to call it like this:

```php
Class:convertDateToUserTimezone($date, 'O');
```

Comment: I was looking here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ and that got me on the wrong road. Is this not the same Carbon?

Comment: @Petar Vsilev You are mixing 2 formatting functions. `format()` defers to PHP's formatting. `isoFormat()` uses ISO formatted stings.

Comment: `->format('Y-m-d H:i:sO')`

Comment: `->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ')`